# Скрипт на Python выдает ошибку else

Tags: python, синтаксис

Код выдает ошибку в строке 20: else SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#подключить математическую функцию sqrt
from math import sqrt
#описание процедуры нахождения дискриминанта и корней
def Solution():
   d = (b * b) - (4 * a * c) 
 #найти дискриминант
print("Дискриминант = {:5.3f}".format(d))
if d > 0: #условие для нахождения двух корней
 #найти значения двух корней
  x1 = (-b + sqrt (d)) / (2 * a)
  x2 = (-b - sqrt (d)) / (2 * a)
print("Два корня:")
 #выдать на экран значения двух корней: x1 и x2
print("x1 = {:5.3f}, x2 = {:5.3f}".format(x1, x2))
Parabola(), Figure()
else: 
if d == 0: #условие для нахождения одного корня
  x1 = - b / (2 * a)
  x2 = x1
print("Корни равны:")
```

Comment: Вы покажите как отформатирован Ваш код для начала. Это же Питон - он не терпит неверного форматирования кода

Answer (score 0):

У Вас  после оператора *else* нет отступа:

```
else: 
if d == 0: #условие для нахождения одного корня
```

Comment: Там еще операторы `print` имеют неправильные отступі в `if` - так что `else` получается потерянный